# Alpine apk: List all available package versions

Tags: linux, bash, package, alpine-linux

How can I list all available package versions of a given package on Alpine Linux?

I couldn't find anything helpful in the apk help.

`apk info bash` only shows me the latest available bash version.

```
# apk info bash
bash-5.0.0-r0 description:
The GNU Bourne Again shell

bash-5.0.0-r0 webpage:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/bash.html

bash-5.0.0-r0 installed size:
1200128
```

Using the `--all` flag I only get some additional info for that version:

```
# apk info --all bash
bash-5.0.0-r0 description:
The GNU Bourne Again shell

bash-5.0.0-r0 webpage:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/bash.html

bash-5.0.0-r0 installed size:
1200128

bash-5.0.0-r0 depends on:
/bin/sh
so:libc.musl-x86_64.so.1
so:libreadline.so.8

bash-5.0.0-r0 provides:
cmd:bash

bash-5.0.0-r0 has auto-install rule:

bash-5.0.0-r0 license:
GPL-3.0-or-later
```

`apk list` and `apk list --available` only list all available packages at their latest version.
So if I run `apk list -a | grep "^bash-\d"`, I only get this:

```
# apk list -a | grep "^bash-\d"
bash-5.0.0-r0 x86_64 {bash} (GPL-3.0-or-later)
```

Answer (score 5):

The command list the info from the lastest branch and Alpine manage package version in different branches for example `v3.5, v3.6.... v3.10`

> The `apk utility` can install packages from multiple repositories. The
>   list of repositories to check is stored in /etc/apk/repositories, one
>   repository per line.

You can search for the version here

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=bash&branch=v3.5

or

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages

So if you are interested to add the version `bash4.3` the should tell the branch name while adding the older version or from other branchers rather then the latest one.

```
apk add  --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/ bash=4.3.46-r5
```

So if you run

```
apk add  --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/ && apk info bash
```

You will get the version info from two different branches.

```
The GNU Bourne Again shell

bash-4.3.46-r5 webpage:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/bash.html

bash-4.3.46-r5 installed size:
700416

bash-5.0.0-r0 description:
The GNU Bourne Again shell

bash-5.0.0-r0 webpage:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/bash.html

bash-5.0.0-r0 installed size:
1200128
```

Comment: But there only seems to be one version per branch. So I only get like 9 versions when I should probably be getting like 100.

Comment: Yes its because all minor versions in same branch